# find remainder of a number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Can anyone help me with this?

> If 738 consecutive integers are added together, where the 178th number in the sequence is 4,256,815, what is the remainder when this sum is divided by 6?

Comment: 738 is divisible by 6 ($738= 123\cdot 6$), therefore you can pair up modulus 6 so the remainder will be 0.

Comment: For the upvoters: nope I was wrong. See Michael's answer.

Comment: If the 178 term is something something specific you know every term in the sequence.  There's a basic formula for adding consecutive terms (or you can just multiply the average bu 738).  Then just divide by 6.

Comment: This is not really a number theory problem, this is a "can I break down a big problem into small problems" problem.

Answer (score 6):

Let the integers be $x, x+1, \cdots, 4256815, \cdots, x+737$. Note that the sum of all of them is equal to $738x+(1+\cdots+737)$. $738$ is divisible by $6$, so the first term is always $0\pmod6$. In addition, we have $1+\cdots+737=\frac{737\cdot738}{2}=737\cdot369$. Note that $369$ is divisible by $3$; however, the product is odd, so it must be $0\pmod3$. Therefore, the sum must be $3\pmod6$, so the remainder is $3$.

P.S. The information that the $178$th number is $4256815$ is extraneous, you do not need it to solve the problem.